# Reload file and save last line position

Tags: c#

I want `save` current position and when I reload file it should start from `saved` position when button is clicked.

For example:

I have loaded file with 10 lines and I stopped on line 5

I reloaded file with new 400 lines and it should start reading from line 5

I have something like this:

```cs
public string readfiles(){
  list = File.ReadAllLines(<path>).Distinct.Reverse.ToList();
  number = list.Count -1;
  msg = list[number];
  list.RemoveAt(number);
  return msg;
}

private void button_click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e){
  response.Text = readfiles();
}

private void reload_click(object sender, ROutedEventArgs e){
  //here should reload file and start with current possition
}
```

I tried:

```cs
public List<string> list(){
  list = File.ReadAllLines(<path>).Distinct.Reverse.ToList();
  return list;
}

public string readfiles(){
  number = list.Count -1;
  msg = list[number];
  list.RemoveAt(number);
  return msg;
}

private void button_click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e){
  response.Text = readfiles();
}

private void reload_click(object sender, ROutedEventArgs e){
  list();
}
```

and

```cs
public List<string> list(){
  list = File.ReadAllLines(<path>).Distinct.Reverse.ToList();
  return list;
}

public int numbers(){
  number = list.Count - 1;
  return number;
}

public string readfiles(){
  number = list.Count -1;
  msg = list[number];
  list.RemoveAt(number);
  return msg;
}

private void button_click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e){
  response.Text = readfiles();
}

private void reload_click(object sender, ROutedEventArgs e){
  list();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't start ReadAllLines from a specific line but you can skip the lines you don't want

```
foreach(var line in list.Skip(5))
  ...
```

Skip is a LINQ thing so make sure you have `using System.Linq` at the top of your file

As to where to put/get the 5, you seem to be using winforms so I'd use the settings system.. Get properties on your project and click Settings on the left. Add a USER SCOPED int called "FileReadFrom" or similar

Now in code you can set/get `Properties.Settings.Default.FileReadFrom` anywhere in the code, and if you remember to `Properties.Settings.Default.Save()` before you quit your app it will remember the setting between app restarts too

Comment: ps; if you file will only ever grow and grow, change to using File.ReadLines; it reads incrementally as you loop which avoids loading the whole file into memory. If you're  doing a `Skip(Properties.Settings.Default.FileReadFrom)` and it's a large number then you're basically loading that many lines you won't ever need if you use File.ReadAllLines; by using ReadLines instead they'll be thrown away as soon as they're read and memory use will be lower